# Python How to display the results as expected format

Tags: python

I am using python to manipulate the Data and display as expected format

Currently I used empty array to append the manipulated data based on the datatype (U8 and U16)

For U8 datatype:`Value = 255`

I am getting the result :`request = 2F f4 0d ['ff', 0, 0, 0]`

I am expecting result should be display by limiting addition bytes:`request = 2F f4 0d ff`

For U16 datatype:`Value = 260`

I am getting the result:`request = 2F f4 0c ['04', '10', 0, 0]`

I am expecting result should be display by limiting addition bytes:`request = 2F f4 0d 04 10`

The code is as below:

```
def EventOnBtnIOControl(event):

#Called the Force Numeric Item to open GUI
ForceNumericItem()

global Value
global CMD

top.wait_window(Subtop)
request = '2F'+ ' '+'f4'+' '+'0d'+' '+ str(CMD)
print request
return
```

My GUI function:

```
def ForceNumericItem():
 Subtop.bind('<Return>', EventForceValue)
 return
```

Clicking Enter

```
def EventForceValue(event):
global Value
Value = SubMenuTakeStrInt()
print SMIScale
fScaledAndOffset = ( ( Value - SMIOffset ) / SMIScale )
print fScaledAndOffset

if (fScaledAndOffset >= 0.0):
    iScaledAndOffset = math.trunc(fScaledAndOffset + 0.5)
else:
    iScaledAndOffset = math.trunc(fScaledAndOffset - 0.5)
print iScaledAndOffset
global CMD

CMD = [0,0,0,0]

if(SMIType == 'u8' or SMIType == 's8'):
    CMD[0] = hex(iScaledAndOffset & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    CMDlimit = 1
    print CMD

elif (SMIType == 'u16' or SMIType == 's16'):
    CMD[0] = hex(( iScaledAndOffset >> 8 ) & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    CMD[1] = hex(iScaledAndOffset & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    CMDlimit = 2
    print CMD
elif (SMIType == 'u24'):
    CMD[0] =  hex(( iScaledAndOffset >> 16 ) & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    CMD[2] = hex(( iScaledAndOffset >> 8 ) & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    CMD[3] = hex(iScaledAndOffset & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    print CMD
elif (SMIType == 'u32'):
    CMD[0] =  hex(( iScaledAndOffset >> 24 ) & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    CMD[1] =  hex(( iScaledAndOffset >> 16 ) & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    CMD[2] = hex(( iScaledAndOffset >> 8 ) & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    CMD[3] = hex(iScaledAndOffset & 0xff)[2:].zfill(2)
    print CMD
else:
    printf(  "Invalid Numeric Data by ID Type", Red )
Subtop.destroy()
top.deiconify()

return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CMD` is

```
CMD = [0,0,0,0]
```

you are displaying it using

```
request = '2F'+ ' '+'f4'+' '+'0d'+' '+ str(CMD)
print request
```

And probably `str` is root of your problem because it will convert list into string representation of list. Maybe you want

```
["{} ".format(i) for i in CMD]
```

instead of

```
str(CMD)
```

or even

```
["{} ".format(i) for i in CMD if i != 0]
```

or more even

```
" ".join([i for i in CMD if i != 0])
```